# How to make function annotation for timestamp

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have an issue annotating my function. Here is the code of the function and the call I am making to it.

```
def poll_notifications(due: datetime.datetime.timestamp) -> Dict:
    pass

now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
due = datetime.datetime.timestamp(now)
test = poll_notifications(due)
```

However when I use mypy for type checking I get an error:
`error: Function "datetime.datetime.timestamp" is not valid as a type`

I am not really sure how to change the type annotation to pass the test. Anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 4):

`datetime.datetime.timestamp` isn't a *type*, it's [a *method* of the `datetime.datetime` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp). And it returns a *float*. And it's supposed to be called on an instance (even though the way you're calling it also happens to work because reasons). So if anything:

```
def poll_notifications(due: float) -> Dict:
    pass

now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
due = now.timestamp()
test = poll_notifications(due)
```

But I'm not sure why you'd construct a `datetime` and then just get a UNIX timestamp from it, instead of passing the much richer `datetime` instance as is:

```
def poll_notifications(due: datetime.datetime) -> Dict:
    pass

due = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
test = poll_notifications(due)
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue. I did that because in poll_notifications function I am gonna be sending a request to a endpoint which requires timestamp format.

Comment: Fine, but internally you should use "rich types", and only convert them to basic types like UNIX timestamps *as needed*. If `poll_notifications` is doing the request to the external endpoint, then it's *its* job to format values as needed.